# jquery $ajax progression

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, loading

Is there away to show how long til the page loads. @ the moment when I send a post request to the sever I send it via the $ajax using post and I have beforeSend showing a message saying we are loading your page. However sometimes it hangs there for a while, It would be great if I could show the user how many % have been sent to the server so they know it is loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function in jQuery that allows you to get callbacks during a AJAX request. And it's difficult to calculate how long a given request will take because everybody's internet speed is different. I don't think it's possible what you want.

You could however change the button that allows your user to send the AJAX request to show a spinner. Spinners are associated with waiting and people tend to be more patient when seeing one.